# Scrape site using Curl returning blank results

Tags: php

What i'm trying to do is do a search on Amazon using a random keyword, then i'll just scrape maybe the first 10 results, the issue when i `print` the html results i get nothing, it's just blank, my code looks ok to me and i have used CURL in the past and never come accross this, my code:

```
<?php

include_once("classes/simple_html_dom.php");

function get_random_keyword() {
    $f_contents = file("keywords.txt"); 
    return $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];    
}

function getHtml($page) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    print "html -> " . $html;
    curl_close($ch);    
    return $html;
}


$html = getHtml("https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=" . get_random_keyword());

?>
```

Ideally i would have preferred to use the API, but from what i understand you need 3 sales first before you are granted access, can anyone see any issues? i'm not sure what else to check, any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should not bypass restriction certain platform has imposed

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: That brings back a load of corrupt text like ���"�͇�&Da �I�E:�ٌ>M�� but it is something to work with, i'm getting closer :) thank you.

Comment: @tess Can also try outputting any error messages: `if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon is returning the response encoded in gzip. You need to decode it:

```
$html = getHtml("https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=" . get_random_keyword());
echo gzdecode($html);
```

Comment: Thank you! i used `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");` which seemed to fix the issue.